# Get all the data in an API that has paging node-fetch

Tags: javascript

I can't get data from another page in an api, below I show how the api returns the data to me.

**hasMore**: true, // when true says there are more pages

**totalCount**: 125, // total amount of items

**limit**: 100, // limit of items per page

**offset**: 0, // offset 0 will return the first page with 100 objects. Using limit 100 and offset 100 will bring the second page, limit 100 and offset 150 to the third page, and so on.

the problem is that i can only get the first 100 items

```
const response = await fetch(baseUrl + "&limit=100&offset=0", {
   headers:{
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
   }
});
let data = await response.json();
```

I have no idea how to get the 125 items in the response as the maximum per request limit is 100
I believe I would have to make two requests for the api.

```
fetch(baseUrl + "&limit=100&offset=0") // returns 100 items from the first page

fetch(baseUrl + "&limit=100&offset=100") // returns 27 items from the second page
```

I want to put these 127 items in response.json.

If it's not too much of a problem, could you show me the way, please?

Comment: you'll definitely have to do 2 calls. if you want all the items, you could do a while loop that keeps making calls and appending to the payload object until hasMore is false

Comment: unless you can set the limit value to more than 100... I'm assuming that is the maximum?

Comment: yes maximum limit is 100, I'm trying it the way you said in the first comment